# Composition of polynomials - is it a simple group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials

I wouldn't be surprised if this can be found maybe even on Wikipedia but I'm not a native English speaker and unfortunately couldn't find this myself.

So for a set of polynomials
$F = \left\{ \, f(x) \mid f(x) = ax+b,\ a,b \in \mathbb{R},\ a \neq 0 \, \right\}$ is the [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) group $\langle \, F; \circ \, \rangle$ [simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group)?

I really tried to contemplate possible [normal subgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup) but don't see any (besides consisting of whole $F$ and $\{x\}$). How to be sure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The group $F$ you are considering is also called the [affine group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group) of the real line. Affine groups of affine spaces of dimension $\ge 1$ always have a non-trivial normal subgroup, namely the subgroup of translations. In particular, they are never simple.

In your case, consider the map $F \to \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ defined by $a x + b \mapsto a$. This is clearly a surjective group homomorphism, and its kernel is the normal subgroup consisting of those polynomials of the form $x + b$, i.e. translations.

Comment: Thank you for a very quick reply. Just to emphasize, so this is the only nontrivial subgroup?

Comment: More generally, affine groups are nontrivial semidirect products of $GL(V)$ with $(V,+)$, so always admit a nontrivial normal subgroup.

Comment: @Pranasas There are many more normal subgroups, but they are harder to describe. This is because $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ itself is not simple.